Trait for a callable class and signature of operator()
Let's say I have a class
template <class T, class Function>
class Integration
{
public:
    T operator()(const Function & f, T a, T b) const
    {
        /// computes the integral of f over [a,b] when f is a function taking a T in
        /// input and returning a T ; it could have not been operator()
    }

computing numerical integration of T-valued functions of one T-valued variable. It is therefore assumed that class Function implements T operator()(const & T) const or some variant of it. (Template parameter T could be any floating point type for instance, or a custom type for automatic differentiation for instance.)
I would like to enforce that condition in some way at compile time. It there a trait for being callable (meaning implementing operator() in some way) with a prescribed signature for the operator ?
(I would like to integrate one variable function with T input and return types, but I could also want to integrate vector<T>-valued function with matrix<T>-values input.)

std::is_invocable. Or, just go ahead and call f in your implementation - if it's not callable, there would be a compiler error pointing to that line.

@IgorTandetnik Are then people bothering with traits only to have more readable compiler errors?

Traits are helpful when you need to do things like "if a type has these properties, do something; if it has different properties, do something else". For example, std::vector copy constructor can use memcpy if the element type is trivially copyable; and otherwise has to copy each element individually, using that element's copy constructor.

@11house Even type traits in meta programing can still give you error messages that are hard to parse.  I personally prefer adding a static_assert in the function body that checks the traits and if that fails then I can have the assert spit out a concise error message.

@IgorTandetnik And if I want to check operator()'s signature, is it still possible ?

@11house If you need to inspect any part of a function (parameter types, number of parameters, whether it's declared "const" in the case of non-static member functions, etc.), my (fully documented) "FunctionTraits" library here (effectively single header only) makes the job extremely easy. See the link for full details. Also see my response here. It shows what's possible with concepts in C++20 or later (as per the op's request) but easy to refactor if you prefer "static_assert" instead.

What do you mean by "check the signature"? If you just want to know whether F can be invoked with a paricular set of argument types, then std::is_invocable is it. If you want to extract the types that F can be invoked with - then not in general; there may be multiple overloads of operator(), and some of them may be template functions.

@Igor Agreed (and upvoted) that disambiguating the overloaded "operator()" you're interested in (if it might be overloaded, though nothing special about "operator()" in this regard vs any other overloaded member function), is an issue, since "&T::MemberFunc" is ambiguous without casting to the specific "MemberFunc" you're interested in (briefly mentioned in the 2nd link of my first comment above). Template versions of "operator()" usually less of an issue in practice though (outside of lambdas), though still always possible of course.

@IgorTandetnik I would say any operator() as I would first like to check if any is available, then their signatures (are they templated or not etc)

C++ doesn't offer reflection at this time. Which is what you are asking for.
